# Prevent deletion of files in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to prevent deletion of all files uploaded to specific folder in Google drive. The idea is several people will be able to upload files to this drive, but they should never be able to delete it.

I thought of putting a Google apps script to achieve this, like letting the script run every x interval and `getTrashedFiles` and set `isTrashed` to `false`. But what if the user is able to delete it from trash too?
Is there a foolproof way?
Or is Google Drive not the right answer at all?
Any other service can help me which is simple for people uploading the files?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

its possible but the way you are doing it isnt practical or tamperproof.

instead write a little apps script webapp that allows uploading files to the given folder where you are owner and only writter.

publish it to run as you with permissions to anyone (or your domain). they will be able to add files and view but not change or remove them (and you will be the owner of all uploaded files).

to support uploading files already in drive (move them to the folder) is also possible but with more code.